# ¿Cómo puedo borrar GameObjects de un List desde otro script? UNITY

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity, game

¡Hola a todos!

Tengo 2 scripts configurados en Unity. El primer script es el EnemyManager que maneja la creación de objetos zombies que aparecerán en cada oleada. Tengo otros scripts para configurar el comportamiento de cada zombie individual.

Cuando creo los zombis, los coloco en un List de GameObjects llamada enemiesList[] para realizar un seguimiento de cuántos zombis hay vivos actualmente. Si eliminan a todos los zombis, se generará la próxima oleada. La condición para esto es si enemigosList.count == 0, entonces puedo generar la siguiente oleada.

El problema que tengo ahora es que cuando elimino un objeto zombi cuando muere, no puedo eliminarlo de la lista de enemigos, por lo que la primera ola nunca termina.

¡Muchas gracias por su ayuda!

```
BaseScript using UnityEngine; using System.Collections.Generic; using System.Collections;
```

Script EnemyManager donde instancio los enemigos, los añado a la lista y se encuentra una función de borrarlos de la lista que no he conseguido que funcione:

```
public PlayerHealth playerHealth;
public EnemyHealth enemyHealth;

public GameObject Zombunny;
public GameObject Zombear;
public GameObject Hellephant;

public float spawnTime = 3f;
public int waveNumber;

public Transform[] spawnPoints; // Array de spawns
public List<GameObject> enemiesList;

public int[] zombieBunnyPerWave;

void Start()
{
    waveNumber = 1;
    Spawn(waveNumber);

    //InvokeRepeating("Spawn", spawnTime, spawnTime); // Pasado el primer spawnTime se llama a la función Spawn y luego cada vez que pase el spawnTime infinitamente
    // Sustituirlo luego por un contador de oleadas
}

private void Update()
{
    if (enemiesList.Count == 0) // O era .Lenght?
    {
        waveNumber++;
    }
}

void Spawn(int waveNumber)
{
    if (playerHealth.currentHealth <= 0f) // Si el player está muerto deja de generar enemigos
    {
        return;
    }
    /*
    int spawnPointIndex = Random.Range(0, spawnPoints.Length); // Elige aleatoriamente un spawn de la lista, hacer que en vez de cogerlos aleatoriamente spawneen de esos puntos la cantidad que le des de cada uno

    Instantiate(Zombunny, spawnPoints[spawnPointIndex].position, spawnPoints[spawnPointIndex].rotation); // Instancia un enemigo en la posición de los spawnPoints
    enemiesList.Add(enemy);
    */
    if (waveNumber == 1)
    {

        /*for (int i = 0; i < zombieBunnyPerWave[0]; i++) // 
        {
            Instantiate(Zombunny, spawnPoints[0].position, spawnPoints[i].rotation);
                Instantiate(Zombunny, spawnPoints[1].position, spawnPoints[i].rotation);
            Instantiate(Zombunny, spawnPoints[2].position, spawnPoints[i].rotation);// Genera enemigos en los 3 spawns                                  
            enemiesList.Add(Zombunny);
        }*/

        for (int i = 0; i < zombieBunnyPerWave[0]; i++) 
        {
            for (int z = 0; z < spawnPoints.Length; z++)
            {
                GameObject newZombunny = Instantiate(Zombunny, spawnPoints[z].position, spawnPoints[i].rotation);
                enemiesList.Add(newZombunny);
            }

        }

        // Otros dos for para los otros dos enemigos
    }


    // Hacer 5 oleadas
}


public void deleteFromList(GameObject newZombunny) // Antes lo tenía sin lo de dentro de los paréntesis
{       
    enemiesList.Remove(newZombunny);
}
```

Script EnemyHealth desde donde estoy intentando borrar el GameObject de la lista:

```
    public int startingHealth = 100; // Valor de vida inicial
public int currentHealth; // Valor de vida actualizada
public float sinkSpeed = 2.5f; // Velocidad a la que el cuerpo del enemigo desaparece
public int scoreValue = 10; // Puntos al matar a este enemigo
public AudioClip deathClip; // Sonido al morir el enemigo

Animator anim;
AudioSource enemyAudio;
ParticleSystem hitParticles;
CapsuleCollider capsuleCollider;

public EnemyManager enemyManager;

bool isDead; // Si el enemigo está muerto
bool isSinking; // Si el cuerpo del enemigo está desapareciendo

void Awake()
{
    enemyManager = GetComponent<EnemyManager>();
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    enemyAudio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    hitParticles = GetComponentInChildren<ParticleSystem>();
    capsuleCollider = GetComponent<CapsuleCollider>();

    currentHealth = startingHealth; // Inicializar la salud actual
}


void Update()
{
    if (isSinking) // Si la variable hundirse está en vd se va a ir hundiendo el cuerpo del enemigo poco a poco
    {
        transform.Translate(-Vector3.up * sinkSpeed * Time.deltaTime); // Se hunde en base a la velocidad marcada en sinkSpeed
    }
}


public void TakeDamage(int amount, Vector3 hitPoint)
{
    if (isDead)
        return; // Comprobamos si el enemigo está muerto, en el caso de que ya lo esté directamente salimos

    enemyAudio.Play();
    currentHealth -= amount; // Restar vida al enemigo

    hitParticles.transform.position = hitPoint; // Posiciono con el transform el efecto de partículas de recibir un disparo y lo activamos
    hitParticles.Play();

    if (currentHealth <= 0)
    {
        Death();
    }
}


void Death()
{
    isDead = true;

    capsuleCollider.isTrigger = true; // Significa lo mismo que la línea de abajo
    //capsuleCollider.enabled = false; // Desactivo el capsule collider

    anim.SetTrigger("Death"); // Reproducir la animación de morir

    enemyAudio.clip = deathClip; // Reemplazar el clip de sonido de recibir daño por el de morir
    enemyAudio.Play();

    //enemyManager.deleteFromList(this.gameObject);
    enemyManager.enemiesList.Remove(this.gameObject);
}


public void StartSinking() // Se llama desde un evento de la anim de morir del enemigo
{
    GetComponent<UnityEngine.AI.NavMeshAgent>().enabled = false; // Desahibilitar el movimiento del enemigo
    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = true; // Deja de verse influenciado por las físicas del entorno
    isSinking = true; // El enemigo empieza a descender
    ScoreManager.score += scoreValue; // Incrementa la puntuación del player

    //enemyManager.deleteFromList(gameObject);
    //enemyManager.enemiesList.Remove(this.gameObject);

    Destroy(gameObject, 2f); // Se destruirá en 2 segs para ver como se hunde en el suelo
}

}
```

Comment: Muy posiblemente no te elimine dela lista el zombi porque el `GameObject` que pasas es diferente al contenido en la lista. Por lo que veo pasas a la lista `this.GameObject` siendo ese `GameObject` un `EnemyHealth` no un `Zombunny`.

Answer (score 0):

Parece que estas tiene un EnemyManager por cada EnemyHealth.

entonces tienes muchas copias de EnemyManager y por lo tanto muchas enemiesList.

*Opcion facil y mal, usa una enemiesList estatica, No recomendado.*

**Opcion recomendable, separa tu EnemyManager en un GameObject aparte de tu EnemyHealth.
Cuando instancies setea el enemyManager de cada zombie, 1 solo enemyManager muchos Zombunny**

```
GameObject newZombunny = Instantiate(Zombunny, spawnPoints[z].position, 
spawnPoints[i].rotation);
EnemyHealth eh = newZombunny.getComponent<EnemyHealth>();
eh.enemyManager = this;
enemiesList.Add(newZombunny);
```

En este caso debes quitar esta linea de tu awake en EnemyHealth

```
enemyManager = GetComponent<EnemyManager>();
```

Tambien te recomiendo quitar esto del update

```
if (enemiesList.Count == 0) // O era .Lenght?
{
    waveNumber++;
}
```

y lo puedes agregar en este metodo

```
public void deleteFromList(GameObject newZombunny)
```